# Elimination Theory (elementary proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Does anyone know an elementary proof of the following fact?

> Fixing $K$ a field, given $p,q \in K[t]$, there is $F \in K[x,y]$ non zero such that $F(p,q) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you refer to by 'elementary', but this statement has a simple proof with field extension.

Since $K(t)$ can be extended from $K(p)$ by adding $t$, it is easy to show that
$$[K(p,q):K(p)]\leq[K(t):K(p)]=\deg p<\infty.$$

That indicates $q$ has a minimal polynomial over $K(p)$, which can be seen as $G(p,q)=0$ where $G\in K(x,y)$. The denominator of $G$ is exactly what we need.